# Long running WCF calls blocks any subsequent request

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

I'm currently hosting a SharePoint WCF web service to make a long running operation. Basically, this operation will make another HTTP request to retrieve information (this other call can take up to 2 min). The code of the service is the following (I stripped some code line):

```
public async Task<Stream> Get()
{
    WebOperationContext operationContext = WebOperationContext.Current;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            operationContext.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";

            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I call this webservice via AJAX from an AngularJS application and the problem is that it is blocking all subsequent calls, even the "normal" ones. For example, when the `GetAsync` method takes 90 seconds to execute, I cannot even switch page in the browser until the method is completely executed... I tried to put the `ConcurrencyMode` to `Multiple` or `Reentrant`, I tried not to use synchronization context and I tried to set the `InstanceContextMode` to `PerCall` but it does not change anything, the server still waits for the call to be completed before handling other action...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, I finally found the issue. The fact is that I was using sessions in my WCF service and in that case, WCF treats calls sequentially, meaning that once a call is started, all the other ones (even a call to switch pages) have to wait that it's done before being treated...

To fix the issue, you have to ask yourself if you're service really needs to be able to **write** in the session. if it does, as far as I know, there is no fixing it. However, if your service just needs to **read** information from your session, you can override your global.asax file with this:

```
if (Request.Path.Contains("myservice.svc"))
{
     HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
}
```

This ensures that WCF are using sessions in read only mode and in that case, the calls can be treated in parallel.